# Identify pattern on filename using batch

Tags: windows, batch, script, filenames, timestamp

I have a script that renames files by adding a timestamp as a prefix to the current filename. A file with a timestamp looks like this:

```
20170407_1030.file1.txt
```

I run this script in a folder after I have worked with some files. The problem is that once a file has already had a timestamp prepended to its name, the next time I run the script it prepends another timestamp to the filename. Instead, if a file already has a timestamp in its name, I want to *replace* it with an updated timestamp.

To accomplish this, I'm trying to identify filenames that already contain a timestamp, and if so, replace it with an updated timestamp.

My script to do this currently looks like this:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "delims=|" %%F in ('dir /b %cd%\*.*') do (
  set "MDate=%%~tF"
  set "Patern=*_*."
  set "TimeStamp=!MDate:~6,4!!MDate:~0,2!!MDate:~3,2!"
  ren "%%~nF%%~xF" "!TimeStamp!-%%~nF%%~xF" 
)
exit
```

Edit: sorry for not providing further details. I've been doing some research and can't find a way to match masks in the given sample. I know how to replace predefined patterns or how to match masks like `ren *.png *.jpg`.

Comment: Thanks for telling us what you want to do. Do you have a question? And if your quesiton is how, please show us what you've tried first! :) It will help so we don't provide answers you've already attempted. If you've attempted nothing, be prepared for down votes! However, the basic log *could* be the number of periods. If not, then your question is not clear as you're not providing enough detail. Regardless, until you [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1225592/edit) I've voted to close. Sorry

Comment: Also, SuperUser is not a "Please write me a script" kind of site. Share your research and we'll help you figure out why things don't work the way they do.

Comment: Added further info.

Comment: Your "question" is still clear as mud, even after the edit. I don't know how to interpret *"I want to identify filenames that already contains a timestamp then update it."*

Comment: Sorry, please see if its clear enough now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Echo off
Pushd "X:\path\to\workdir"

:: Get current date time 
For /f "delims=." %%A in (
  'wmic os get LocalDateTime^|findstr ^^[0-9]'
) do Set DT=%%A
Set "DT=%DT:~0,8%_%DT:~8,4%"

For /f "tokens=1* delims=." %%A in (
  'Dir /B/A-D "20*_*.*.txt"^|findstr "^20[0-9][0-9][01][0-9][0-3][0-9]_[0-2][0-9][0-5][0-9]\." '
) do Echo ren "%%A.%%B" "%DT%.%%B"
```

If the output looks OK, remove the echo in the last line.

Sample output:

```
> SU_1225592.cmd
ren "20170704_1656.File1.txt" "20170704_1700.File1.txt"
ren "20170704_1656.File2.txt" "20170704_1700.File2.txt"
```

**Edit** To just check a file for the existence of a date_time pattern
you can use this batch which uses only the errorlevel returned from findstr
to conditionally execute on succes `&&` or fail `||` different commands.

```
@Echo off
Set "Pattern=^20[0-9][0-9][01][0-9][0-3][0-9]_[0-2][0-9][0-5][0-9]\."
For %%A in ("%CD%\*") Do Echo:%%~nA|findstr "%Pattern%">NUL 2>&1 && (
    Echo found Pattern in %%~fA
) || (
    Echo No    Pattern in %%~fA
)
```

Sample output:

```
No    Pattern in A:\Copy+Archive.cmd
No    Pattern in A:\SU_1225592.cmd
found Pattern in A:\20170704_1656.File1.txt
found Pattern in A:\20170704_1656.File2.txt
No    Pattern in A:\tp010387.BAT
```

Comment: Although this is not the answer I was looking for, it leaded me straight to the solution. Thanks.